# Force "Tab" clicks to move within an element - Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a div having role of "dialog" type  I want to lock focus on Tab Key press inside a dialog box. There is already Close button added in that dialog. Currently as soon as dialog  opens
my focus comes on first input button and then on TAB key press my focus moves to close button inside that dialog. 
Now  third time when I press TAB key then focus moves to my back page's input element. That mean focus comes outside of that dialog. 
How can I lock my focus inside dialog so that until dialog is closed it do not move outside of it. 
Is there anyway to set `tabindex="-1"` of my back page's input element so when Dialog reflect on screen and we press TAB key focus do not move 
on that elements.
My HTML code is mentioned below. It will give you just rough idea.

```
// code for dialog
    <div style="display: none">
    <div aria-live="assertive" aria-describedby="Contentdiv" 
    role="dialog" id="completeReservationMain" >
                <div tabindex="-1"  id="Contentdiv">

                    <div  id="CompleteReservationContent"> 


                        <h2 tabindex="-1" class="help-layer-heading"> 

                           Print   </h2>


                        <div tabindex="-1" class="check-in-complete-help">
                            Are you sure to Submit?
                        </div>
                        <div class="center">
                            <span class="Button" id="Span1"><span class="ButtonInner">
                                <form method="get" target="_blank" action="/Print.aspx">
                                <input type="submit"  id="confirm" value="Print">
                                </form>
                            </span></span><span class="Button " id="Span2">
                                <span class="ButtonInner">
                                    <input type="submit" title="Submit" id="confirmSubmit" value="Continue Submit">  
                                </span></span>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                   </div>
```

Now below mentioned code is of my Normal HTML page, where I have button, when I click over it then dialog opens:

```
 <body>

 <div class="topMenu" id="main">

        <div title="Home" >
            <a href="/Home.aspx" id="home"> Home  </a>
              </div>    

        <div title="Services" >
            <a href="/Services.aspx" id="services"> Services  </a>
              </div> 

              <div title="Contact" >
            <a href="/Contact.aspx" id="home"> Contact </a>
              </div> 
 </div>
  <div class="print-contract">
  <form action="https://example1.com">
            <div class="button">

                    <input value="Print" type="submit" id="print" title="Print" />
            </div>
            </form>

            <form action="https://example2.com">
            <div class="button">

                    <input value="Complete Reservation" type="submit" id="completeReservation" title="Complete Reservation" />
            </div>
            </form>
            </div>

            </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can remove focusability from an input field. But you can listen for tab keypresses and control that behavior. (I guessed which one was the close button, switch them if I'm wrong.)

```
$("#confirmSubmit").keydown(function(e){
    if (e.which == 9 ) { //keycode for TAB
        e.preventDefault(); //stops the default behavior of moving focus to the back page
        $("#confirm").focus(); //moves focus to your first input button
    }
});
```

Comment: I have added your solution in my JS like this: $(function () {
    $("#confirmationLayerCompleteCheckInButton").keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 9) { 
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $("#confirmationLayerPrintButton").focus();
        }
    });
});  but it's not working. Can I remove function from it??

Comment: Yeah, keep it just as it is. Or possibly put it inside your $(document).ready(function(){   });, if you have one of those.

Answer (score 0):

You can check every time **tab** is pressed whether the focused element is inside the *dialog container* or not. If not, then just focus on the first element in the *dialog container*.

```
$('body').on('keydown',function(e){
  var dialogHidden = $('#completeReservationMain').parent().is(':hidden');//according to the html code given
   // Also checking if dialog is hidden or not
  if($(':focus').closest('#completeReservationMain').length == 0 && e.which === 9 && dialogHidden === false ){
    // for example on the confirm button
    $('#confirm').focus();
  }
});
```